# Replace 2nd part of list returned with function squared

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

As mentioned above, I want to replace the 2nd part of a list returned from a function with the 2nd part squared.

```
n[s]:= {1*s,2*s};
ReplacePart[n[s],2->?^2]
```

I need the question mark to equal the current value returned. What is the most concise way of doing this with or without ReplacePart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

```
n[s]:= {1*s,2*s}; 
n[s]/.{y_,z_}->{y,z^2}
```

which returns `{s,4s^2}`

You can also write that as

```
ReplaceAll[n[s],{y_,z_}->{y,z^2}]
```

If the list may or may not have more than two elements then

```
ReplaceAll[n[s],{y_,z_,x___}->{y,z^2,x}]
```

will maintain any additional elements unchanged

Comment: I came up with 2 other ways:
1. a = n[s];ReplacePart[a, 2 -> a[2]^2]
2. MapAt[Power, n[s], {2}]

I love the way you do it. Pattern matching right? Between yours and these alternatives, what would be the most readable, standard way to do it?

Comment: Either way, thank you so much for your previous answer. I really appreciate it. I come from Python, and can't figure out the best way to handle functional programming in Mathematica yet. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: There are always at least half a dozen different ways of doing anything in Mathematica, or Python. There is a culture in Mathematica of trying to write things in the shortest, and sometimes more cryptic, way. Mastering a few standard ways of doing things so that you can dependably use them is probably most important. It can take a while to understand a very different way of programming. Using `/.` and `->` is probably what you will see used most often. Buying a cheap used copy of a book like "Mathematica Navigator" might help you get started with the language. Good luck with your new language.